# Where can I publish my paper for free?

Tags: geography, publishing, references

Is there any magazine (or some other such place) where university students can publish a GIS/Geo related article freely (in English or French)?

Comment: this link provides a list of open access geo related journals http://www.oajse.com/subjects/geography.html

Comment: See http://www.digital-geography.com maybe

Comment: Hi laechoppe,

I was suprised to see my blog www.digital-geography.com here on stackexchange as a way to publish things. We are open for your article.

Comment: But as far as I know, open access papers are often accompanied with costs on the authors side as they will be for free to read/access for readers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer :

- http://digital-geography.com
- http://geoawesomeness.com

In another case, I fear that you need to go through academical review process e.g like for [HAL](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/index.php?langue=en) or [CyberGeo](http://cybergeo.revues.org) (both for French papers mainly)

Answer (score 4):

[PLOS ONE Geographic Information Systems](http://www.plosone.org/browse/geographic_information_systems) is an open access peer-reviewed journal that may meet your needs.  You can find publication criteria [here](http://www.plosone.org/static/publication).  The beauty of this publication is that it is available freely to the public, which has wide implications for scientific research.

> Everyone can freely access and download all PLOS ONE articles without
>   paying subscription fees, pay-per-view charges, or any other
>   restrictions. Publishing open access makes it easier for others to
>   access your research, and it may also help you comply with your
>   funder's policies regarding open access publication and
>   indexing/archiving.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what you mean by "freely":

You can publish your article also as a student in every paper you like as it will go through the publication/review process like all the other papers. It will be for free for the author.

Try to find a professor who will support you and review your article beforehand: It will be probably easier for you to get into a magazine with the support of a professor.

Also conferences are a good starting point to have the possibility to publish things.

But like ThomasG77 mentioned: you can publish your things on my blog digital-geography.com where we have an English and a French section...